# Parse ACLs in Client

Tags: security, parse-platform

Are ACLs supposed to go into the client code when using parse? This seems not secure to me because can't someone just change the ACL code when creating a new object? Perhaps I am just misunderstanding...

Would appreciate some clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Moving security to the client allows an attack to bypass the security by sending network messages directly to your server. Access control must always be checked on the server.

That said, it can frequently improve the user experience if you add permission-based UI elements. Depending on your implementation, the decision to show conditional elements can be made on the client or the server. For example, you may wish to show additional UI elements if the current user has admin privileges. Whether you use ACLs directly for that or an application-specific means of making the decision is largely a matter of choice. The key thing is that, even though you may have conditional UI, you **always** check permissions on the server as well.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of Parse to not have a server though? If I needed to write a server to check ACLs, I might as well not use Parse.

Comment: The Parse Cloud handles the ACL checks so you don't need to write the server.